# Which will be more efficient to em-place in following?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, stdvector

I wrote a code as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using type = std::vector<std::string>;

int main()
{
    int query = 5;

    std::vector< type > answer;  
    answer.reserve(query);

    auto vecReturn = [](const std::string& x, const std::string& y) -> decltype(auto)
    {
        std::vector<std::string> tempVec = {x, y};
        return tempVec;     // removed std::move() from here
    };

    while(query--)
    {
        std::string xName, yName;
        std::cin >> xName >> yName;
        answer.emplace_back( vecReturn(xName, yName) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I can rewrite the above without the lambda function, something like follows:

```
using type = std::vector<std::string>;
int query = 5;
std::vector< type > answer;  // group set
answer.reserve(query);

while(query--)
{
    std::string xName, yName;
    std::cin >> xName >> yName;

    type tempVec = { xName, yName };
    answer.emplace_back( tempVec );
}
```

Which looks pretty less code than the first one. Now the question is,

1. Is there any **efficiency differences** between in these two ways, considering that, `query` could be up to the maximum integer numeric limit.
2. If so, which one of above mentioned ways, would you suggest me to do?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you looked at the generated assembly code and/or done any benchmarks?

Comment: @UnholySheep : I am sorry, I don't know about this. I am just a c++ beginner(high school) and never tested such things before. If you don't mind, could you suggest some links or where/ how to do it?

Comment: I'm fear that `return std::move(tempVec);` returns dangling pointer, remove the `move`.

Comment: @Jarod42 : I though, that might make more efficient, since we move the vector from the function and not copying. will compiler automatically do the same for me, even if I don't do the same, in this case? I have a small confusion about it? or Am I wrong about it?

Comment: As you have `decltype(auto)`, version with `move` would return reference instead of value. with return type as `auto`, no longer dangling pointer, but your `move` would avoid (N)RVO so would be "less" efficient (optimizer might resolve to the same code BTW with as-if rule).

Comment: I would probably do `answer.push_back({xName, yName});`. I suspect the other solutions will be optimized to produce roughly the same code that that will. But you really need to measure and see..  Given that the process is pausing to read input, I suspect that will overshadow any potential savings you may make here.

Comment: @Galik: or even `answer.push_back({std::move(xName), std::move(yName)});`

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes. Although those strings just get re-allocated the next time round the loop so it may be a zero sum gain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does a copy:

```
type tempVec = { xName, yName };
answer.emplace_back( tempVec );
```

It should be

```
type tempVec = { xName, yName };
answer.emplace_back( std::move(tempVec) );
```

then both code would be equivalent.

Note that you may even move the string to avoid string copies.

Comment: thanks for explaining me all. I went through the comment/ conversation section and was really helpful to know the basics. However, now I have another a serious issue regarding `std::move`, when I used for `std::unique_ptr<>`, which we may talk in another question.